# RecyclerView within RecyclerView is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a layout SwipeRefreshLayout as parent and within that I am using RecyclerView within RecyclerView. Inner recyclerview is not scrolling. I have tried multiple solution available on this website but not resolve my problem.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and recyclerview item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why -ve, I am facing this problem and answer available on stackoverflow is not solve my problem.

Comment: Why do you need two RecyclerViews? How should be determined which RecyclerView must scroll when swiping?

Comment: I am showing multiple users in parent recyclerview and in child recyclerview show connected devices for particular user.

Comment: Maybe you need something like a tree. I suggest you provide more information about what you want to achieve. I think the missing information is the reason for all the downvotes

Comment: Items of inner recyclerview is not scrolling in case of multiple item.

Comment: Maybe the ExpandableListView can do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)